# Replacing the sequence \r\r\n with the \r\n in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd, line-breaks

I need to create a batch file that executes a tool to generate some files, and then passes those files to some other tool.

But the problem is the the 1st tool generates the sequences of `\r\r\n` where line breaks should be. So I need to replace those sequences with just `\r\n`.

`1.txt`

```
line number 1

line number 2

line number 4

line number 5
```

I tried this approach

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "SEARCH_TEXT=`r"
SET "REPLACE_TEXT="
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (1.txt) DO (
    SET "string=%%A"
    SET "modified=!string:%SEARCH_TEXT%=%REPLACE_TEXT%!"
    ECHO !modified!>>"2.txt"
)
```

But it only replaces `\r\n\r\n` with `\r\n`

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: I bet the source of the text file content is the `wmic` command. Anyway, the following works: `(for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "1.txt"') do @for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ("%%L") do @echo(%%F) > "2.txt"` (this would remove leading colons though, but this could easily be solved when needed)...

Comment: Thank you very much!
It works. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer then...

Answer (score 0):

Such additional (orphaned) carriage-return characters can occur when trying to convert Unicode text to ASCII/ANSI text using a `for /F` loop. A classical example is to capture the Unicode output of the `wmic` command by a `for /F` loop.

To ged rid of these conversion artefacts simply add an additional `for /F` loop:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to target directory (the parent of this script, for instance):
cd /D "%~dp0."
rem // Write output to file:
> 2.txt (
    rem // Loop through lines of file, prefix each with ine number plus `:`:
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" 1.txt') do (
        rem /* Use another loop to get rid of additional carriage-return characters;
        rem    the `tokens` and `delims` options split off the line number prefix: */
        for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ("%%L") do (
            rem // Output current line with the line number prefix removed:
            echo(%%F
        )
    )
)
```

The interim line number prefix (line number plus colon) mentioned in the comments is intended to not lose empty lines since `for /F` ignores such. The inner loop then removes the prefix after having the line processed by `for /F`, using its `tokens` and `delims` options. This would also remove any leading colons from lines. If this could actually occur, then change the inner loop to this to keep these `:`:

```cmd
        rem // Use another loop to get rid of additional carriage-return characters:
        for /F "delims=" %%E in ("%%L") do (
            rem // Store current line:
            set "LINE=%%E"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Output current line with the line number prefix removed:
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
            endlocal
        )
```